# How to do multibinding using Kodein dependency retrieval container?

Tags: dependency-injection, kotlin, kodein

I do migration from Dagger 2 to Kodein and want good alternative to [multibinding](https://google.github.io/dagger//multibindings.html) feature. Is there one?

Comment: I'm the author of Kodein. At the moment, Kodein 4.0 does not include this feature. I will be posting a reponse once it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kodein `4.1.0` has just been released and now supports [multi-binding](https://salomonbrys.github.io/Kodein/#_multi_binding).

I hope it does answer your needs.

Comment: Thank you for a great library, feedback and that feature!